# Unable to change camera position when using VRControls

Tags: javascript, three.js, virtual-reality

I have the following code:

```
...
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, screenRatio, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.z = -10; // position.set(0, 0, -10) also not working.
controls = new THREE.VRControls( camera );
effect = new THREE.VREffect( renderer );
effect.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
...
```

VRControls are working in sync with the accelerometer, but I can't change the cameras position. It seems stuck in the origin point (0,0,0). It was working just fine before applying VRControls and VREffect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution inside Sechelt demo from [Mozilla VR Team demos](http://mozvr.github.io/webvr-demos/). I'll put here a code snippet as reference for other VR beginners.

Adding the camera to a group instead of updating the camera position directly is the way to move the camera.

```
var scene, renderer, cameraRatio, camera, controls, effect, dolly;

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    cameraRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, cameraRatio, 1, 1000 );       

    controls = new THREE.VRControls( camera );
    effect = new THREE.VREffect( renderer );
    effect.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    // This helps move the camera
    dolly = new THREE.Group();
    dolly.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
    scene.add( dolly );
    dolly.add( camera );

    ...
    // Of course, there should be lights, objects, etc
}

function animate() {
    dolly.position.x += 0.1;
    controls.update();
    effect.render( scene, camera );
}

init();
animate();
```

Comment: I dont't know exactly why dolly group is necessary to change position of the camera. Is VRControls always overriding the camera position to origin?

Answer (score 0):

I think the camera is now the `object`. You can try `object.position.set()` instead.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in VR mode, for some reason.