# ThreeJS not rendering Cube with setAnimationLoop

Tags: javascript, three.js, webvr

So I'm working on a ThreeJS WebVR Page. (I'm quite new to three.js)

So I tired to make a basic scene to test some stuff. But when I load the page with `renderer.setAnimationLoop(render)` I get my green cube for 1 Frame and then it disappears.

(I got it working with `requestAnimationFrame()` but this will not work with WebVR)

This is my code for my test sandbox:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); 
renderer.vr.enabled = true;

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00ff00
});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

function render() {
  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function animate() {
  renderer.setAnimationLoop(render);
}

animate();

//Button vor start VR Session
document.body.appendChild(WEBVR.createButton(renderer));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the problem with setAnimationLoop 
The problem is you cannot set camera position when vr is enabled 
check this stack overflow question
[Unable to change camera position when using VRControls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470248/unable-to-change-camera-position-when-using-vrcontrols)

Check this [CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxevpz) where i fixed your code by changing position of cube instead of camera

```
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
cube.position.z = -5; //added this instead of camera.position.z = 5;
```

if you want to move the camera you need make it as child of another object and set the position to that object